# Binding to an element name from within a style

Tags: wpf, binding, styles

I have an application which has context menu drop downs from a button.  The drop down menu is implemented using a style on the button.  I want to be able to enable or disable a particular item in the context menu based up on the number of files in a list view.  The converter I have for this works just fine (I can attach it to an unstyled button and it enables or disables it just fine), however when I attach it to the context menu item, it fails.  I'm sure that this is because the Binding can't find the element I'm referring to because it's within the style, but I'm unsure how to point it in the right direction.

```
<Button Name="buttonDropDown" BorderBrush="LightGray" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Padding="2,0" >
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Click">
                    <EventTrigger.Actions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="ContextMenu.IsOpen">
                                    <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="True"/>
                                </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger.Actions>
                </EventTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Header="Option 1">
                            <MenuItem.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="opt1_Click"/>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.Style>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Option 2">
                            <MenuItem.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="opt2_Click"/>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.Style>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="Option 3" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=fileListView, Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource fileCountConverter}}">
                            <MenuItem.Style>
                                <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                                    <EventSetter Event="Click" Handler="opt3_Click" IsEnable="{Binding ElementName=fileListView, Path=Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource fileCountConverter}}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.Style>
                        </MenuItem>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Grid x:Name="Chrome" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                            <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFc2e0ff"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF3399ff"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FFc2e0ff" />
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF3399ff"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
```

The converter is below just for reference:

```
class FileCountConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int count = (int)value;
        if (count == 1)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere you use the `FileCountConverter` in you code, also except some `TemplateBindings`, there is not any Binding here. At least you should post exactly the code you tried (although it does not work).

Comment: Ugh, you're right sorry I'd removed it as part of some testing I was doing elsewhere.  I've added the binding back into Option 3